# Translate Tcl List to Python List

Tags: python, list, tcl

I try to translate Tcl list to python list.

There are two problems:

- If a list in the original list contains only a single list, the translation is incorrect. For example, `{{12 34}}` is not correctly translated.
- The option to convert all numbers to a type does not work.

Python 3 code:

```
import tkinter


class TclInterpreter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._tcl = tkinter.Tcl()

    def eval(self, tcl_cmd):
        return self._tcl.eval(tcl_cmd)


class TclPyListTranslator(object):
    def __init__(self, tcl):
        self._tcl = tcl

    def to_py(self, tcl_list, dtype=str):
        # convert a Tcl List to python list, also convert elements of each leaf
        # node to dtype
        self._tcl.eval("set tcl_list %s" % tcl_list)
        numItems = int(self._tcl.eval("llength $tcl_list"))
        if numItems > 1:
            result = [self._tcl.eval("lindex $tcl_list %d" % i) for i in range(
                numItems)]
            for i in range(numItems):
                result[i] = self.to_py("{" + result[i] + "}", dtype)
        else:
            result = dtype(self._tcl.eval("lindex $tcl_list %d" % 0))
        return result


inter = TclInterpreter()
translator = TclPyListTranslator(inter)
tcl_list = "{12 {{12 34}} {56 {78 {11 12} 10}}}"

# prints ['12', '12 34', ['56', ['78', ['11', '12'], '10']]]
# The '12 34' is incorrect
print(translator.to_py(tcl_list))

# does not run
print(translator.to_py(tcl_list, int))
```

Comment: Do you _know_ that the leaves are numbers? Or do you have to handle things like the string `this is an awkward example`?

Comment: sometimes I do, sometimes I don't. So I leave that as an option. If the dtype is set to int, then I expect the leaves are all numbers. Otherwise, I just leave the leave nodes as strings.

Comment: `"{12 {{12 34}} {56 {78 {11 12} 10}}}".replace("{","[").replace("}","]").replace(" ",",").replace("\t",",").replace("\"",",")` to literal_eval.

Comment: may be tkinter is a bad idea. @dsgdfg double white space breaks that one, but let's hope things like that won't show up.

Comment: Can the list have an arbitrarily deep set of sublists?

Comment: @BryanOakley: For now, only a depth of about 3... I tried to search online for Tcl List traversal, but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Trying Tcl `foreach` now.

Comment: If you have the freedom to install extra packages, you might want to consider converting the tcl list to json on the tcl side, and then deserializing it on the python side. I'm not sure how easy that is on the Tcl side, my Tcl is pretty rusty.

Comment: There's a package for generating JSON for Tcl in [tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/json/json_write.html). However it doesn't really solve the problem of knowing when you've got leaves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python parser:

```
def add_element(cache, element):
    if element != '':
        cache[-1].append(element)
    return ''

def parse(tcl_list):
    """ Parse TCL list to Python list """    
    out = []
    cache = [out]
    element = ''
    escape = False
    for char in tcl_list:
        if escape:
            element += char
            escape = False
        elif char == "\\":
            escape = True
        elif char in [" ", "\t", "\r", "\n"]:
            element = add_element(cache, element)
        elif char == "{":
            a = []
            cache[-1].append(a)
            cache.append(a)
        elif char == "}":
            element = add_element(cache, element)
            cache.pop()
        else:
            element += char
    return out[0]
import pprint
pprint.pprint(
    parse("{ 12 apple {100} {} {{12 34}} \n {56\n { \\{78 {11 12 11} 10}}}"))
```

output:

```
['12',
 'apple',
 ['100'],
 [],
 [['12', '34']],
 ['56', ['{78', ['11', '12', '11'], '10']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of handling this is to get the code on the Tcl side (which natively understands Tcl lists) to generate the string form of the Python value and then `eval` that within Python. However, the complex part is that Tcl's type system is really utterly different to that of Python (to the point where I don't intend to explain it as it's an intensely complex and technical argument), making deciding where the leaves of the nested list structure non-trivial. Some assumptions are required. With those assumptions, we can do a pretty decent job in not too much code.

The Tcl side code you need is something like this (in the case where you need leaves that are integers):

```tcl
proc toPythonList {value} {
    if {[string is integer -strict $value]} {
        return $value
    }
    set result "\["
    foreach item $value {
        append result [toPythonList $item] ", "
    }
    append result "\]"
    return $result
}
```

That then means you can do this (and I've added a *very simple-minded* version of the adaptation for different types of leaves):

```python
class TclPyListTranslator(object):
    def __init__(self, tcl):
        self._tcl = tcl
        self._tcl.eval("""
            proc isLeaf.int {value} {
                string is integer -strict $value
            }
            proc isLeaf.str {value} {
                expr {![string match "{*}" $value]}
            }
            proc toPythonLeaf.int {value} { return $value }
            proc toPythonLeaf.str {value} { return "\"$value\"" }
            proc toPythonList {value dtype} {
                if {[isLeaf.$dtype $value]} {
                    return [toPythonLeaf.$dtype $value]
                }
                set result "\["
                foreach item $value {
                    append result [toPythonList $item] ", "
                }
                append result "\]"
                return $result
            }
        """)

    def to_py(self, tcl_list, dtype=str):
        # convert a Tcl List to python list
        return eval(self._tcl.eval("toPythonList %s %s" % (tcl_list, dtype.__name__))
```

*WARNING: The code above **should** work, but I can't test it as I don't have tkinter configured in any of my Python interpreters. The pieces work on their own though, so I'm reasonably confident.*

Comment: Adding support for more types to the code is left as an exercise. Be aware that there are other differences between Tcl and Python that can trip you up as well, such as the differences between boolean constants and the different ideas of what dictionaries are. My code is _not_ general!

Comment: I tried to translate a tcl list that only has integers. But It can't distinguish leaves. `puts [toPythonList { 12 {100} {{12 34}} {56 {78 {11 12 11} 10}}}]` gives `[12, 100, [[12, 34, ], ], [56, [78, [11, 12, 11, ], 10, ], ], ]` http://rextester.com/LVKCI83006

Comment: It would be a good idea to replace `eval` with `ast.literal_eval` because you only need parsing, not actual evaluation. That reduces the chance of a security risk in case of a possible bug in `toPythonList`.

Comment: @rxu If you want anything more sophisticated than this, you're probably going to have to start by writing a much fuller set of use cases. This sort of thing is where TDD really comes into its own.

Comment: I just wrote a python parser that seems to work. I don't know Tcl enough to know if I miss any corner cases.

Answer (score 1):

I had a need to do this today and used the accepted answer as a starting point, however, it did not take into account strings containing spaces. For example: `{hello world "foo bar"}` would result in `['hello', 'world', '"foo', 'bar"']` rather than `['hello', 'world', 'foo bar']`

Here is a modified implementation:

```
class TCLListParser(object):

    NO_ESCAPE = 0
    SINGLE_ESCAPE = 1
    STRING_ESCAPE = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self._out = None
        self._buffer = None
        self._stack = None

    def _flush(self):
        if self._buffer is not None:
            self._stack[-1].append(self._buffer)
        self._buffer = None

    def _add_char(self, char):
        if self._buffer is None:
            self._buffer = char
        else:
            self._buffer += char

    def parse(self, tcl_list):
        self._out = []
        self._stack = [self._out]
        self._buffer = None

        escape = self.NO_ESCAPE

        for char in tcl_list:
            # Single escapes
            if escape & self.SINGLE_ESCAPE:
                self._add_char(char)
                escape &= ~self.SINGLE_ESCAPE
            elif char == '\\':
                escape |= self.SINGLE_ESCAPE
            # Strings with spaces, like "hello world"
            elif char == '"':
                escape ^= self.STRING_ESCAPE
            else:
                if escape & self.STRING_ESCAPE:
                    self._add_char(char)
                elif char in [" ", "\t", "\r", "\n"]:
                    self._flush()
                elif char == "{":
                    _ = []
                    self._stack[-1].append(_)
                    self._stack.append(_)
                elif char == "}":
                    self._flush()
                    self._stack.pop()
                else:
                    self._add_char(char)
        return self._out[0]

parser = TCLListParser()
pprint.pprint(parser.parse('{ 12 "big apple" {100} {} {{12 34}} \n {56\n { \\{78 {11 12 11} 10}}}'))
```

result:

```
['12',
 'big apple',
 ['100'],
 [],
 [['12', '34']],
 ['56', ['{78', ['11', '12', '11'], '10']]]
```